# How to make a node partially selected in JQuery FancyTree?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

How to make a node partially selected?
For example, I have two lazy nodes:

[image]

Now I expand the first one:

[image]

The node "1" has wrong state until children are loaded. I want to set state in advance, before node is expanded. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node.partsel` attribute is used to mark this state:

```js
  {title: "Lazy node", lazy: true, partsel: true},
```

However, as of version 2.30, the `partsel` flag is reset after initial load.
An [issue was opened](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/939) to address this.